# Function substitute

Tags: haskell

How can I do a function (recursivily) that substitute the argument b(1) for an argument a(0) on a list?
For example:

```
    substitute 0 1 [1,0,3,0,4,0,0]
    [1,1,3,1,4,1,1]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest is to use list comprehension:

`subst a b xs = [c | x<-xs, let c=if x==a then b else x]`.

But that's no recursion. With recursion, it is just a case analysis for list structure (i.e. structural recursion):

```
subst a b [] = []
subst a b (x:xs) 
   | x==a      = b:subst a b xs
   | otherwise = x:subst a b xs
```

which is an instance of the `foldr` (or `map`) pattern:

```
subst a b = foldr (\x xs-> (if x==a then b else x) : xs) [] 
subst a b = map   (\x   ->  if x==a then b else x      )
```

It is usually advisable to use a "worker" function in recursive definitions, like so:

```
subst a b xs = go xs
  where
    go [] = []
    go (x:xs) 
       | x==a      = b:go xs
       | otherwise = x:go xs
```

but if you stare at it for a moment you recognize that it is follows the `map` pattern. In Haskell recursive patterns are captured by higher-order functions, like `map`, `filter` etc.

Answer (score 6):

No recursion required!

```
substitute :: Eq a => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
substitute old new = map subs where
    subs x | x == old  = new
           | otherwise = x
```

If this is homework, you can easily substitute in the [definition of `map`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/GHC-Base.html#map) (which *is* recursive).